# Is it possible to use evaluateImage twice on the same image?

Tags: php, html, imagemagick, imagick

We are creating a tool to build an image out of several images, as seen here: https://www.kalaharikats.com/custom-kat We are attempting to change the edges of a marking by using evaluate image as a whole number, an effect that we achieved quite by accident when building the opacity portion of markings. What I am wondering at this point is if it is possible to use evaluateImage in the Imagick library twice on the same image? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: At this time, the code runs evaluateImage() once for opacity and once for edging. Edging is our troublesome portion of the script. Both use Imagick::EVALUATE_MULTIPLY, with opacity using a 0.01-1 range and the other using 1 to 100. I can, if necessary, include the code in question and screenshots, but felt that having the live tool handy might serve better.

Edit 2: I have included the code section in question. :-)

```
            $image->evaluateImage(Imagick::EVALUATE_MULTIPLY, $marking->get('opacity') * 0.01, Imagick::CHANNEL_ALPHA);

            $image->evaluateImage(Imagick::EVALUATE_MULTIPLY, $marking->get('edging'), Imagick::CHANNEL_ALPHA);

            $image->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_EXTRACT);
```

Edit 3: We have some screenshots that may help. Please download them [here](https://www.kalaharikats.com/kk_images.zip); we had to make a zip file as they were to big to attach to this question. :-)

Comment: Yes, it's possible to call the function twice, but if it works it depends on the type of operation that you run with it. Have you tried? What happens to your image.

Comment: I'm editing my question in just a moment to further explain our issue. <3

Comment: Adding more detail in hopes of more helpful feedback. <3